# query ui asset is returning error 403 on Apache and Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm adding a dynamic behavior on my input control, using:

```
var options = {
    source: ["ActionScript", "AppleScript"]
};
var selector = '.input_autocomplete_workspacedocuments ';
$(document).on('keydown.autocomplete', selector, function() {
    $(this).autocomplete(options);
});
```

This code is working ok different enviroments. But now, I'm using xampp and apache and it's returning the error:

```
jquery.js?rev=2:6700 GET http://localhost/LawFortress/public/assets/themes/default/jquery/smoothness…:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7 403 (Forbidden)
```

I'm not using the default xampp configuration. How I can fix it?

I read a lot of stackoverflow threads saying that I could modify:

httpd.conf and httpd-xampp.conf (grant all), but it's not working

**httpd.conf file**

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: show ur httpd.conf. And you will need to set the correct permission for your folders.

Comment: @Mox I just added it in the question.

Comment: @MrMins Can you try to load same `gif` in `img` tag directly?. May be `gif` mime type not allowed from setting.

Comment: @jagad89 yes, I can. Accessing directly via URL it's possible, but the requets is triggered by a jquery ui autocomplete behavior

Comment: @MrMins Have your tried after deleting your cache and cookies ?

Comment: @jagad89 yes, I tried it, but still not working

Comment: @MrMins Your code and everything looks perfect. Only issue with server setting.  I am looking on internet, i will comment back if i will find something.